# Python - Custom Color Shape File

Tags: python, shapefile

I'm opening a csv file that associates some of the provinces of Canada a number between 0 and 7. I'm adding this number to the shapefile as a new column. I'm wondering how to assign the color based on the colors list I have below with the hex codes.

The code below works, but the colors coming out are default-selected by the program, but I want to assign the specific colors based on the index position in the colors list, which also exists in the csv and is added as a column to the shapefile.

I tried working with LinearSegmentedColormap but couldn't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

[current colors that I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQTLv.png)

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

with open('canadadata.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    header = next(reader)

# Store states in dictionary keys, and price as values
    forsaledata = {}
    for row in reader:
        k = int(row[3])
        v = int(row[2])
        forsaledata[k] = v

# open shapefile
canada = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('lpr_000b16a_e.shp')

# create new column with shapefile data
canada['color'] = np.zeros(len(canada))

# assign colors to each province in the new column
canada.ix[0, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(0,8))
canada.ix[1, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(1,8))
canada.ix[2, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(2,8))
canada.ix[3, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(3,8))
canada.ix[4, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(4,8))
canada.ix[5, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(5,8))
canada.ix[6, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(6,8))
canada.ix[7, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(7,8))
canada.ix[8, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(8,8))
canada.ix[9, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(9,8))
canada.ix[10, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(10,8))
canada.ix[11, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(11,8))
canada.ix[12, 'color'] = int(forsaledata.get(12,8))

# establish colors, 9th color/index 8 is white
colors = ["#f7fbff", "#deebf7", "#c6dbef", "#9ecae1", "#6baed6", "#4292c6", "#2171b5", "#084594", "#ffffff"]

canada.plot(column='color')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. It just took some trial and error to get it right.

```
colormap = []
colormap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],colors)
canada.plot(column='color', cmap = colormap)
```